# How to Find all unclosed html tags and close them using preg_replace()

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to fix the html tag closing on my site, my users are posting data  that is not properly formatted, (sometime they forget to close the html tags and it makes their post look ugly).

So I tried preg_replace, but it doesn't work

This is my string :

```
 $upost="<html><body><b>Hello world!<b></body><html>";
```

Tag B and Html are not closed, I want my code to find all unclosed tags and correct them.

```
echo preg_replace("/.*|^<[^>]+>[^>]+<([^>]+)>/i","</$1>",$upost);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Don't. At least, [not with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/507674).

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // basically hide 'em, we don't care
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($upost);
$upost = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Adjust as needed, but this will parse it as best it can and return well-formed HTML.